# Docker varnish error 503 backend fetch failed

Tags: docker, dockerfile, varnish

Here is **default.vcl**

```
vcl 4.1;
backend default {
  .host = "127.0.0.1";
  .port = "8080";
}
```

My **docker-composer.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  varnish:
    image: varnish:stable
    container_name: varnish
    volumes:
      - "./default.vcl:/etc/varnish/default.vcl"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    tmpfs:
      - /var/lib/varnish:exec
    environment:
      - VARNISH_SIZE=2G  
    depends_on:
      - "node" 
  node:
    build: ./
    container_name: node
    ports:
      - "8080:8000"
```

My **Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY package*.json ./

USER node

RUN npm install

COPY --chown=node:node . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

When I run the application through http://localhost:8080/ it works and when I run it directly in port 80 like this http://localhost/ it throws

> Error 503 Backend fetch failed

Am I missing out something in configuring port? Or How can I check the varnish log through docker?

Comment: You've told the Varnish cache to proxy itself (`localhost`); you probably need to use the other container's Compose service name `node` as a host name instead.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes the host names and other setup available to you.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you changing 127.0.0.1 to node works in `default.vcl` file